Are old Winterbash leaderboards still available?
I tried to search for old Winterbash leaderboards but I always get redirect on a blog page.
Is there a way to see old leaderboard pages or are they lost forever?

They are not available on Stack Exchange, but the Wayback Machine may be of help.
Links like these list various (sub)pages of the leaderboards, both network-wide and per site. Of course, many pages won't be available or contain a copy from earlier moments when the Winter Bash wasn't finished yet.


Thanks for answering, but unfortunately it doesn't have all the sites. If they are lost forever that's sad, we should have an official archive.

@pinckerman The data is indeed gone. Part of the setup process each year was running a dev-only "delete-all-the-things" path which, well, emptied everything out of the database. We don't keep archives because the data is all gone.

@animuson that's a pity, but thanks anyway

since the sunsetting of winterbash there are not many links referring to Winterbash remaining active.
There is an overview of Stackexchange contests available with links to the some charts of WB. Those charts are images and show only a limited number of rankings.
besides that there are some blogs, resuming each year's bash activity, also with very limited rankings in image only
WB2022
WB2021
you can find more on stackoverflow.blog searching for bash

Yeah, I found the same links
